# How long before I get the Werewolf Hunter hat?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

The [Werewolf Hunter Hat](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/werewolf-hunter):

> earn a silver badge

I got the epic badge more than 24 hours ago and I still have not got the hat. Timeline below:

- `2014-12-26 23:41:39Z` Got a +1 that pushed me past the 200 rep limit
- `2014-12-27 xx:xx:xxx` Logged in few hours later and noticed that I have epic badge dated `2014-12-26 00:00:00Z`
- `2014-12-28 07:59:02Z` is the current time and no hat.

Comment: Hats are awarded in batches. It'll be there soon enough! :-) (And congrats!)

Comment: @MartijnPieters It looks like they were awarded the epic badge more than one day ago. Is this normal? I don't recall such a large delay for any of the hats I've received.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary are 'backdated' to midnight. I got my [Meta legendary badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=100297) recently, it was awarded [in the late afternoon](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20598803#20598803) but the date on the badge is still set to midnight.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Ah OK. The timestamp is `2014-12-26 00:00:00` though and now it is `2014-12-27 15:47:42` so this means they have been waiting nearly 16 hours even if it was actually awarded at  `2014-12-26 23:59:59`?

Comment: @MartinSmith: no, it was awarded about an hour ago, even though they crossed the threshold the day before.

Comment: Oh I see. Because that runs in batches too.

Comment: I see you still haven't received this three hours after posting. 

As an experiment I found someone without the Werewolf Hunter hat and a good +24 answer that I hadn't previously upvoted and tipped them over to a good answer.

They received the badge after 3 mins and the hat 5 mins after that so your wait does seem unusually long. 

Hopefully the hat allocation script does take account of the back dating and doesn't just do a `WHERE badges.awarded >= @lastrun`

Comment: I'll wait 5 more hours (till 2014-12-28 00:00:00) and see if I get the hat.

Comment: OK, waiting did not help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - "Soon Enough" = "6 to 8 weeks"?

Comment: @MartinSmith: looks like a bug here; it could be that with the back-dating the hat awarding is failing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - My money's on a bug too. Unless it only checks this condition less frequently (say daily) but running out of time for this to be a possible explanation as this question is coming up to 23 hours old.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I poked Balpha (main Winter Bash Stack Exchange developer).

Comment: Please don't vote to close [status-completed] questions as 'can no longer be reproduced'. That's kinda obvious from the tag itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by an optimization that's meant to decrease work when awarding hats by only looking at recently awarded badges, and that didn't take the peculiarity of the Epic badge into account (it counts as awarded at the start of the 50th rep cap day). I have removed that optimization for the badge-based hats, and you have just been awarded the Werewolf Hunter. Sorry about that, and thanks for the bug report!